# Countable intersection of 1/k vs epsilon

Tags: real-analysis

$\{x\in E|f(x)\ge c\}=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{{\{x\in E|f(x)>c-1/k\}}}$
I saw this statement many times, but I think $\{x\in E|f(x)\ge c\}=\{x\in E|f(x)> c-\epsilon\}, \forall \epsilon\in \mathbb R^+ $ and $\epsilon$ is uncountable right?
why we can use countable the intersection here? Looking forward answer. Thank you
!

Comment: What specific reason can you give for why it matters if the intersection is over $ \epsilon > 0 $ or over $ k \in \mathbb{N} $?  Why don't you write down explicitly the definition of set intersection.  Always refer to definitions over intuition in a situation like this where your intuition cannot be trusted.

Comment: Because of the nested-ness of the sets over which you are taking the intersection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

$$\{x\in E|f(x)\ge c\}=\{x\in E|f(x)> c-\epsilon\}, \forall \epsilon\in \mathbb R^+$$

means that
$$\{x\in E|f(x)\ge c\}=\{x\in E|f(x)> c-\epsilon\}$$

is true for all $\epsilon\in \mathbb R^+$. Of course this is wrong. The correct statement is
$$\tag{1} \{x\in E|f(x)\ge c\}=\bigcap_{\epsilon \in \mathbb R^+} \{x\in E|f(x)> c-\epsilon\}$$
and this can be checked easily.

The question why
$$\tag{2} \{x\in E|f(x)\ge c\}=\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{{\{x\in E|f(x)>c-1/k\}}}$$

holds because $\{1/k\}$, as a sequence, tends to zero (essentially, by Archimedian property). To check (2), $\subset $ is easy. On the other hand, if $x$ is in the RHS, then

$$ f(x) > c-1/k$$
for all $k\in \mathbb N$. Informally if you take $k\to \infty$, then $f(x) \ge c$ and you are done. A bit more precisely, if $f(x) < c$, then $f(x) < c- 1/k$ for some  large $k$ (by Archimedian property), which is a contradiction. Thus $f(x) \ge c$ must be true.

So (2) and (1) are both true. However, (2) is much more useful (since, e.g., countable intersection of measurable sets is measurable).

Comment: Please refresh your memory and review the Enforcement of Quality Standards published in meta.math.se.